# How I end loop which external variable?

Tags: python-2.7, socket.io

```
        def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    if message = 'something' : break
    else:
 while: 
    socketio.emit('msg',message )
```

Problem is when the program is in the loop it cannot take external variable. How to fix it?

Comment: Where does this external variable come from?

Comment: if come from mqtt server . "message" variable is changed every time for some external interface.

Comment: There is another issue in your code: invalid sintax in `while:` line. This won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If `message` is changed somehow from outside you can make it global and create an intermediate varibale to store the value in it:

```
def on_message(client, userdata):
    text = message // the value of message was changed somewhere outside
    if text == 'something':
        do your stuff
    else:
        do your stuff
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if text =='something' :`

Comment: can not break this loop  
test = x['message'] 
 
 while True:
  if test == 'Presence': 
   break;
  else:
 
   socketio.emit('topic_all',t)
   socketio.emit('admin', admin_data)
   time.sleep(5)

Comment: You have to assign `test`  INSIDE the loop. Otherwise its value won't change.

Comment: `test = x['message'] 
 
 while True:
  if test == 'Presence': 
   break;
  else:
 
   socketio.emit('topic_all',t)
   socketio.emit('admin', admin_data)
   time.sleep(5)`

Here was code structure. I assign text inside loop